# Why am I getting shopping trolley notifications about local store savings?

Tags: notifications, google-maps, ads, google-assistant

I am getting "Shopping Trolley" notifications appearing regularly.
The notification looks like this:
[image: Notification shopping trolley]

The notification is about "Store savings" at a local supermarket and that is it!
[image: Notification details]

Is this notification from Google Maps or another application like Google Assistant? I'm struggling to find the specific setting to disable the notification.

I am also interested to know if this notification could in any way be targeted advertising generated by the store. My marketing preferences with the store are opt-out and this strikes me as very dumb advertising. Surely Google isn't doing this? Is there a means that a store can generate notifications like this? Could it be targeted if they have my email address?

These are pain and I want to understand why they are spamming me and disable them without disabling everything else.

I can see various options under Google Maps, settings, notifications. Which setting would apply? Could it be "New on maps, Get occasional updates about new features in your area"? I can't see what setting to suppress!

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notification isn't from Google Maps at all, but from Google Assistant a.k.a. Google Now. All the notifications with the G icon are from that app. It's not controlled by the store or targeted to you: it's just about the place that Google thinks you're at. The location update rate isn't very fast (to save energy use), so sometimes you only see the notification after you've already left, or just if you go past the place.

To control it, start the **Google** app or swipe your homescreen left to open the Google Now page. Then press the "hamburger" icon (looks like ≡) to open the navigation drawer, and choose **Settings**. From there, scroll down to **Your feed** and click that. On the next page, scroll down past **Get notified about** to see a list of all the types of Google Now card you can get notified about. **Places** is the one about nearby places. You can also turn off all the notifications at once on this page.

Note that turning off the **Places** option will also hide the similar notifications about restaurant and bar reviews, timetables when you're in a bus or train station.