# Every time I walk past a hotel

Tags: alerts

...my phone thinks I need to know what amenities the hotel has. I've managed to shut off most of the other annoying alerts my phone wanted to throw out, but this one I haven't found in the menus. Where do I go to tell my phone I don't need to know about every hotel?

Comment: First you have to find out which app is pushing those messages. If you got the app you can disable notifications for that app: https://www.howtogeek.com/204187/how-to-disable-app-notifications-in-android/

Comment: The notifications are coming from the "Google" app. Looking over its notification options, I don't see an option for "Hotels" I can turn off. And "Google" is not an app whose permissions I can afford to revoke entirely.

Comment: Although it sounds different, this is exactly the same feature that causes problems in [Why am I getting shopping trolley notifications about local store savings?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196177/why-am-i-getting-shopping-trolley-notifications-about-local-store-savings), and my answer there also applies to these notifications.